# Overriding PrimeFaces renderer not working when provided via module library

Tags: jsf, overriding, faces-config, custom-renderer

I have a very tricky problem when overriding JSF-renderers.

This is a part of my faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
          version="2.0">
    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
            <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.MenubarRenderer</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>de.mycompany.web.MenuRenderer</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
    <factory>
        <exception-handler-factory>de.mycompany.web.ValidationExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>
</faces-config>
```

The structure of my web-project is following

- webapp (building war), Dependencies to core and gui
- core (building jar)
- gui (building jar), Dependencies to core, containing xhtmls and @Named Beans, Dependency to com.sun.faces:jsf-impl Version 2.1.25

When I place the content of the faces-config.xml in
webapp/src/main/webapp/META-INF or
core/src/main/webapp/META-INF
both, the MenuRenderer and the ValidationExceptionHandlerFactory, are getting used. Yeah.

When I place the content of the faces-config in
gui/src/main/webapp/META-INF
the ValidationExceptionHandlerFactory is getting used, but not the MenuRenderer. WTF?

Also all other features (phase-listeners, system-event-listeners I use in my faces-config are working except ones in the render-kit-nodes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to override a renderer supplied by another external library, not a standard renderer.

The loading order of `faces-config.xml` provided by external libraries is by default undefined. In your specific case, your library is apparently loaded **before** PrimeFaces library is loaded.

You can explicitly specify the loading order via `<ordering>` element in `faces-config.xml`. The name of the PrimeFaces library is [`primefaces`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources-maven-jsf/standard-faces-config.xml). So, just add the below entry to your `faces-config.xml`. Make sure you supply your library a name too so that endusers can in turn reorder in their own `faces-config.xml` if necessary.

```
<name>yourlibrary</name>

<ordering>
    <after>
        <name>primefaces</name>
    </after>
</ordering>
```

A real world example can be found in e.g. [OptimusFaces](https://github.com/omnifaces/optimusfaces/blob/develop/src/main/resources/META-INF/faces-config.xml) which also extends PrimeFaces.